# square zero extensions, abelian group objects in a category, module categories

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $\mathcal{C}$ the category of commutative rings over $A$. Let $\mathcal{C}_{ab}$ denote the category of abelian group objects in $\mathcal{C}$, its elements $(B,p)$ are a map $p:B \to A$ of rings with maps $0:A \to B$, $+:B \times_A B \to B$, and $-:B \to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ satisfying the usual group axioms. It is a fact that the category of $A$-modules $Mod_A$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{C}_{ab}$, and I am trying to find out how this equivalence goes. I know one direction: given an $A$-module $M$, form the ring $A \oplus M$ by defining $(a, m)\cdot (a', m') = (aa', am'+_Ma'm)$, and let $p(a, m)=a$, so $p:A \oplus M \to A$ is an element of $\mathcal{C}$. $(A \oplus M, p)$ lies in $\mathcal{C}_{ab}$ by defining $(a,m) + (a,m') = (a,m+m')$, and $0(a,m)=(a,0)$ and $-(a,m)=(a,-m)$.

My question is how to go the other way. Given an object in $\mathcal{C}_{ab}$, say $q:B \to A$ and maps $+,0,-$, let $M=\ker(p)$; I want to construct an isomorphism $f:(B,q) \to (A \oplus M,p)$. Define the map $f:B \to A \oplus M$ by $f(b)=(q(b), b-0q(b))$. I can show $f$ is a bijections of sets, by I am having trouble showing $f$ is a ring homomorphism (specifically $f(bb')=f(b)f(b')$). Also, I think I need to use the map $+:B \times_A B \to B$.

Comment: Did you look at the nLab page about Beck modules?

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks. I didn't know about Beck modules, but yeah, I'm trying to understand Quillen cohomology. The page had exactly what I was looking for.